Defining the completion of a group can be done only using Cauchy sequences
Let $G$ be a group, in Atiyah & MacDonald's Commutative Algebra it says that

Assume for simplicity that $0\in G$ has a countable fundamental system
of neighborhoods. The completion $\hat G$ of $G$ may be defined in the
usual way by means of Cauchy sequences.

What do they exactly mean by this? I understand that it makes the group topology first countable. What is the statement that makes this sufficient, what does it mean for it to be sufficient?

First countable groups are metrizable.

Continue reading on the same page. They explain, explicitly, what they mean by $\hat{G}$.

@uniquesolution They say that it is enough to consider Cauchy sequences to define the completion and then they define the completion using Cauchy sequences. I can't see why it indeed is enough.

@SteveD Thank you for the insight but why is it enough then for metrizable spaces? I really cannot seem to find this information, largely because I don't know what to actually look for.

It's the same construction as when you construct the real numbers from the rational numbers using Cauchy sequences.

@Ted Yes I can see that but why then do we not consider Cauchy filters or Cauchy nets but instead consider Cauchy sequences that for that construction.

I'm not really sure what you're getting at. In a metric space, sequences are good enough for the construction to go through, and we don't need to use nets or filters.

@Ted Maybe what I am asking is too trivial. You just said that "sequences are good enough for the construction to go through." What I wonder is the meaning of that sentence. Good enough as in what? What property do sequences satisfy in a metric space (or a first countable group) that they do not satisfy otherwise.

There's too many details to write here. Review the construction of real numbers from rational numbers using Cauchy sequences. You'll see that it applies to any metric space X - you construct another metric space "completion of X" from X.

I can't figure out what you're asking really. "good enough" means "sufficient to construct the completion". Can you be more precise about what you're not understanding? There are lots of ways to build the completion, A-M is choosing to do it with Cauchy sequences. What's wrong with that?

@SteveD Here is another way to ask it: saying that Cauchy sequences are sufficient for constructing the completion means that the completion has some other definition and our construction / definition actually aligns with that definition in our case. What is that definition, and why is it satisfied only using Cauchy sequences in our case?

No, it does not mean that the completion has some other definition. Instead, it means this: You can use the concept of Cauchy sequences to write the definition of the completion.

@LeeMosher Then isn't your sentence just meaningless? If there is no other definition that I need to adhere to, then I can just use literally anything to define the completion as long as it makes logical sense.

Sure, you can define a pencil to be a cat, if you like; good luck getting it to write for you. You seem to be avoiding the point: by using the definition of Cauchy sequences in a topological group, you can then write a definition of completion which is an analogue the definition in metric spaces, and you can the prove the various properties that the completion ought to obey by generalizing the proofs that work in metric spaces.

This happens over and over again: a concept which works well in one realm (e.g. completion of metric spaces using Cauchy sequences) can be adapted, by analogies and other methods, to make it work as well in another realm (e.g. completion of topological groups).

You can also read about uniform spaces and their completions: Every topological group has a natural uniform structure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space
